# How do I extract (rip) tracks from an audio CD using cdrfte?

Tags: windows, mp3, compact-disc, ripping

On its [SourceForge page](http://cdrtfe.sourceforge.net/cdrtfe/index_en.html), it says that cdrfte (short for cdrtools front end) can extract files from CD in mp3 format. However, I can't find anything on its support wiki or anywhere else about how this is done. How do I rip mp3s using cdrfte?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using cdrfte for this? There are much easier ways to rip CD's.

Comment: @James I find cdrtools to be simple, fast, and elegant and all I want is a front end to use them for ripping mp3s.

Answer (score 0):

From the `cdrft` page:

> cdrtfe is an open source CD/DVD/BD burning application for Microsoft
>   Windows. You can burn data discs, Audio CDs, XCDs, (S)VCDs and
>   DVD-Video discs. It supports creation and writing of ISO images and
>   bootable discs. Disc images and Audio CDs can be written
>   simultaneously to multiple writers.
>
> cdrtfe is a win32 frontend for the cdrtools (cdrecord, mkisofs,
>   readcd, cdda2wav), Mode2CDMaker, VCDImager and other well-known tools.
>
> cdrtfe has a multi-language interface and is also available as
>   portable version. For Windows 9x, ME, 2k, XP, Vista, 7.
>
> cdrtfe is free software since version 1.1pre4 (GNU General Public
>   License).

So, it does not make mp3s. What made you think it does? It can *extract* wav files from CDs which you can then encode as mp3 using an mp3encoder, yes. But it does not seem to have the encoder built in. Why should it? That is not what cdrtools does.

Comment: From the cdrtfe homepage (http://cdrtfe.sourceforge.net/cdrtfe/index_en.html) in the list under "cdrtfe supports the following features:" ... "extract audio tracks to wav, mp3, flac or ogg"

Comment: Well, you're quite right, so it does. Sorry, I missed that. Still, `cdrtfe` seems to be a frontend for the `cdrtools`. The only relevant of those here is `cdda2wav` which [cannot deal with on the fly mp3 encoding](http://www.cdda2wav.de/faq.html#mp3-coding). My guess is that they mean you can rip your CD to .wav and then transform to mp3.